# Read php file and get specified data

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to read a PHP file and copy specified data to another PHP file.

The php file has multiple lines like this:

```
, (2, 'Bridge of Spies', '2015-11-26', NULL, 8.1, NULL)
, (3, 'Everest', '2015-09-17', NULL, 7.3, NULL)
, (4, 'The Martian', '2015-10-01', NULL, 8.2, NULL)
```

I only need the title from the each line.
For example from `, (2, 'Bridge of Spies', '2015-11-26', NULL, 8.1, NULL)` I only need the text Bidge of Spies.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use a regular expression based approach, so `preg_match()`.

Comment: Have you read any of TFM?

Comment: So I just read the file line by line and then use preg_match() on that line?

Comment: Try this https://regex101.com/r/VhYXf9/1

Comment: Wow that works great!

Comment: You don't need regex. Open file -> read line -> explode line -> test array[1]. Rinse, lather, repeat for each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$titles = [];
$handle = fopen('./test.data', 'r');
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        preg_match('/^,\s+\(\d+,\s+\'([^\']+)\',.*\)$/u', $line, $tokens);
        if (!empty($tokens)) {
            $titles[] = $tokens[1];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
print_r($titles);
```

The output of above code obviously is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bridge of Spies
    [1] => Everest
    [2] => The Martian
)
```

if you use a `test.data` file with such content:

```
bla bla bla
, (2, 'Bridge of Spies', '2015-11-26', NULL, 8.1, NULL)
, (3, 'Everest', '2015-09-17', NULL, 7.3, NULL)
, (4, 'The Martian', '2015-10-01', NULL, 8.2, NULL)
bla bla bla
```

Definitely the regular expression itself can be optimized, but that depends on your actual situation. I just tried to sketch the general approach.

Comment: Why not just use `explode`? Or `fgetcsv`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sure, also possible, but you'd have to do some post processing. Also `explode()` would stumble over commas inside the title...

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!